# How to set color of area surrounded by GLGridItem in PyQtgraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

After some changes of the GLGridItem.py I am able to set its color but still fail to fill the area surrounded with the grid with custom color.

This is the snipped of my code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np


app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.opts['distance'] = 20
w.show()

grid = gl.GLGridItem(size = QtGui.QVector3D(3,3,1), color=(1,1,0,1))
w.addItem(grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

It currently draws following grid:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this (for e.g. the area surrounded by the grid should be blue)?

Edit:

If one is happy with using zero-height GLBarGraphItem() for drawing area of given color, the following might be a way to go:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np
import itertools

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.opts['distance'] = 20
w.show()

size, pos = np.empty((1,1,3)), np.empty((1,1,3))
size[...,0:2], pos[...,0:2] = 3, -1.5
size[...,2], pos[...,2] = 0, 0

area = gl.GLBarGraphItem(pos, size)
area.setColor((0., 0., 1., 1.))

grid = gl.GLGridItem(size = QtGui.QVector3D(3,3,1), color=(1,1,0,1))
w.addItem(grid)
w.addItem(area)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

It actually produces the following outcome:

[image]

Comment: Instead of publishing the solution in your publication it is best that you publish an answer, and that you mark it as correct in 2 days, that is the way to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setBackgroundColor](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glviewwidget.html):

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np
import itertools

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.setBackgroundColor('b')
w.opts['distance'] = 20
w.show()

grid = gl.GLGridItem(size = QtGui.QVector3D(3,3,1), color=(1,1,0,1))
w.addItem(grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

[image]

Also, for future questions, snippets are strongly discouraged in favor of a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (or MRE). I've added some extra imports to make the code run.

Comment: From what I understood the OP wants to fill in color the grids, not the window.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I think you're right. From the docs it looks like there is no way to fill in the individual facets.

Comment: Exactly, for that reason the OP is asking that question

Comment: @eyllanesc, you are right, my aim is to fill just the grid with custom color, I will have to implement paint() or some other method on my own, that's why I asked for help here.