# python openGL: How to change the color of a grid?

Tags: python, opengl

win I am just starting with some 3D graphics experiments using python and openGL but I am already struggling trying to change the color of a grid, because I want a black grid on a white background. 
I simply copied the pyqtgraph example GLSurfacePlot.py and changed the line

```
g = gl.GLGridItem ()
```

to any of these, but none changed the color:

```
g = gl.GLGridItem (size = QtGui.QVector3D(10,10,1), color = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) )
g = gl.GLGridItem (size = QtGui.QVector3D(10,10,1), color = (1, 1, 0, 1) )
g = gl.GLGridItem (size = QtGui.QVector3D(10,10,1), color = 'k')
g = gl.GLGridItem (size = QtGui.QVector3D(10,10,1), color = pg.glColor((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)) )
color = QtGui.QColor("b")
g = gl.GLGridItem (size = QtGui.QVector3D(10,10,1), color = color)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have win 10, python 3.7, pygtgraph 0.10.0, PyopenGL 3.1.5, PyQt5 5.11.3

thanks for any help

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a bug in GLGridItem, it does not use `color` parameter in its constructor:

```
def __init__(self, size=None, color=None, antialias=True, glOptions='translucent'):
     GLGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
     self.setGLOptions(glOptions)
     self.antialias = antialias
     if size is None:
         size = QtGui.QVector3D(20,20,1)
     self.setSize(size=size)
     self.setSpacing(1, 1, 1)
```

and just directly sets the white color with 30% transparency when drawing it:

```
def paint(self):
    .......................
     glColor4f(1, 1, 1, .3)
    .......................
```

If you want to set the color of the grid you can either modify the standard module (use a color parameter in constructor) or copy the code from the module to your code and use it instead of the standard GLGridItem:

```
def __init__(self, size=None, color=None, antialias=True, glOptions='translucent'):
     GLGraphicsItem.__init__(self)
     self.setGLOptions(glOptions)
     self.color = color
     self.antialias = antialias
     if size is None:
         size = QtGui.QVector3D(20,20,1)
     self.setSize(size=size)
     self.setSpacing(1, 1, 1)

def paint(self):
    .......................
    if self.color is None:
       glColor4f(1, 1, 1, .3)
    else:
       glColor4f(*self.color)
    .......................
```

Comment: Hi Alex,thanks for your answer. Before asking I was searching for an answer and I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796096/how-to-set-color-of-area-surrounded-by-glgriditem-in-pyqtgraph claiming that he changed the color and showing a screenshot that seemed to prove it.

Comment: Also I tried to move GLGridItem to my code, naming it myGLGridItem.This works fine as long as I don't give a color when instantiating the griditem. If I do so the graphics is unstable, when trying to move it with the mouse while in fact it does not move and there are a lot of errors in the console window.

Comment: I found the second one myself:
the else-part in paint must be 
glColor4f(self.color [0], self.color [1], self.color [2], self.color [3]) because color is a tuple with 4 values. Now it works smooth,Thanks again Alex.

Comment: You can use `glColor4f(*self.color)` to unpack the tuple in place. Also, if this answers your question you can mark the answer as excepted :)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again for the unpack tuple hint, Everything works fine now. I clicked the check mark for your answer ;-)